# select values from different columns mysql, how do I tell which is which?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE username='$user1' OR username='$user2' LIMIT 2";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
$email1 = $row[0];
$email2 = $row[1];
```

Just trying to select email from 2 columns and identity which email belongs to which username. Email1=user1 and email2=user2, is what I seek.

Comment: can you give an example on haw's that whcih is whcih

Comment: Go ahead SO, show me how you vote down quetions from non experts

Comment: SELECT usename, email FROM users WHERE username in ('$user1' ,'$user2') LIMIT 2

Comment: how do I know whether email1 belongs to user1 or user2

Comment: @stkmedia i didn't down vote any thing , just asking on how it wokrs

Comment: in your result set  each record will contain two column with user name and email

Comment: You're query is wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should look into [Prepared Statetments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @PacMan ah yeah, no, I been looking through manual and sometimes shy away from SO cause, y'know, noobish questions get punished sometimes, it was before your comment

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka The $user1 and $user2 variables are usernames, just wanting to match up the email to username, is there a more efficient statement or is mysqli fetch row not the way to go?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the $user1 and $user2 are previously cleaned by a preg_replace statement. how is it open to injection? I'm asking because I don't know

Comment: `preg_replace` is **not** a good way to sanitize your data. Considering the complexity of regular expressions, there's even a risk that you make things worse. Anytime you concatenate a SQL-query-string with user input, you're more or less vulnerable for injections (including using `mysqli_escape_string` and such). Prepared statements sends the query and the parameters separately to the database server and let the server handle it's sanitation and inclusion in a much better way, which removes the risk for injections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT username,email FROM users WHERE username='$user1' OR username='$user2' LIMIT 2";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query))
{
    $email[ $row[0]] = $row[1];

}
mysqli_free_result($row);
```

Hope it will help..

expected output

```
$email['user1']= email1
$email['user2']= email2
```

Comment: The output is in the while loop or is it after the free result?

Answer (score 1):

As written, each row would contain only a single email address.

You'd be better served selecting an additional column that identifies the user, such as an id or username.

Then each row would contain both the email and the identifying data associated with that email. If more than one row is matched, you'll need to fetch additional rows to determine that, or else use an aggregate query.

```
$sql = "SELECT username,email FROM users WHERE username='$user1' OR username='$user2' LIMIT 2";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
    $username = $row[0];
    $email = $row[1];
    // do some checking
}
```

Also, be sure the values of $user1 and $user2 are safe before sending...

Comment: Suggestion, change `mysqli_fetch_row()` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` and you can retrieve the values with `$row['username']` and `$row['email']` instead. Just a bit easier. :)